# How to stop funciton looping?

Tags: java, function, while-loop

I'm working on a simple tic-tac-toe 4x4 game. I have input() function where user enters his data, printBoard() which prints the board itself, analyzeBoard() where are all the calculations for choosing the winner and done() which simply returns status. My problem is that even when I find the winner I can't stop input() working and it keeps printing board over and over. For the first time, I thought that problem is in analyzeBoard() but then I figured out that it actually returns everything I need and the problem is in input(). When I try to return from input, it either says missing return statement either just doesn't stop even though it can see the winner.

```
public char input ()
{   
    while (status == false || numberOfMovesLeft > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("User "+ whoseTurn + " enter your move: "); //prompt user to make a move
        char userInput = reader.next().charAt(0); // local variable to hold user input

        // validation of user input
        while (userInput != 'a' && userInput != 'b' && userInput != 'c' 
            && userInput != 'd' && userInput != 'e' && userInput != 'f' 
            && userInput != 'g' && userInput != '1' && userInput != '2'
            && userInput != '3' && userInput != '5' && userInput != '6'
            && userInput != '6' && userInput != '7' && userInput != '8'
            && userInput != '9')
        {
            System.out.println("Try again, user "+ whoseTurn + " enter your move: ");
            userInput = reader.next().charAt(0);
        }

        // places user input into a board cell
        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++)
            {
                if (board[row][col] == userInput)
                {
                    board[row][col] = whoseTurn;

                }
            }
        }

        // check for tie result
        numberOfMovesLeft--;

        if (numberOfMovesLeft==0)
        {
            System.out.println("Tie!");
            winner = 'T';
            System.out.println(winner);
        }
        analyzeBoard();

        printBoard();

        done();
        whoseTurn = (whoseTurn == 'X') ? '0' : 'X';
    }
    return winner;
}

public void analyzeBoard()
{
    // row winner algoritm
    for (int row = 0; row <=3; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 2; col++)
        {
            if (board[row][col] == board[row][col + 1] 
                &&
                board[row][col] == board[row][col + 2])
            {
                System.out.println("winner");
                winner = whoseTurn;
                System.out.println("winner "+ winner);
                System.out.println("whoseTurn "+ whoseTurn);
                status = true;
                System.out.println("status "+status);
                done();
            }
            else
            {
                //System.out.println("status "+status);
            }
        }
    }

    //column winner algoritm
    for (int row = 0; row <2; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col <= 3; col++)
        {
            if (board[row][col] == board[row+1][col] && 
                    board[row][col] == board[row+2][col])
            {
                System.out.println("winner");
                winner = whoseTurn;
                System.out.println("winner "+ winner);
                System.out.println("whoseTurn "+ whoseTurn);
                status = true;
                //System.out.println("status "+status);
            }
        }
    }

    //diagonal winner algoritm
    for (int row = 0; row <2; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col <2; col++)
        {
            if (board[row][col] == board[row+1][col+1] &&  
                    board[row][col] == board[row+2][col+2])
            {
                System.out.println("winner");
                winner = whoseTurn;
                System.out.println("winner "+ winner);
                System.out.println("whoseTurn "+ whoseTurn);
                status = true;
                //System.out.println("status "+status);
            }
        }
    }

    //diagonal winner algoritm
    for (int row = 0; row <2; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 2; col <=3; col++)
        {
            if (board[row][col] == board[row+1][col-1])
            {
                System.out.println("winner");
                winner = whoseTurn;
                System.out.println("winner "+ winner);
                System.out.println("whoseTurn "+ whoseTurn);
                status = true;
                //System.out.println("status "+status);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Matex is right but as i see there may be more problems in your code. if you would explain it more i would be able to help you

Comment: you exit only if there is a winner and there are no more moves left.. Is this what you mean in your while condition?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `break;` to terminate current loop or `return;` to terminate entire function call.